# Jar to dmg conversion

Tags: java, macos, javafx, executable-jar

Hi all please tell how to build setup for mac system from .jar files.

I just tried jar bundler but in that file no main class is available

please let me know as quick as possible

Comment: Are you building on a mac? I'm not aware of any way to create a dmg file on a non-mac platform, but you could just ZIP the `.app` bundle you get out of the bundler.

Comment: am developed my project in Eclipse and i has my entire project in .jar(Executable) file .. so i has software to create setup for Windows.. But i would like to know.. how to make setup for Mac OS

Comment: Is There any other Suggestion for creating an Setup file for Windows.. Please Let me know as quick as possible.. Suggest any Idea??

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html

Comment: Hi can u send the screenshot for doing this buddy.. i need more explanation from u

Answer (score 0):

I read this article for creating installer in MAC OX.
http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/

Though its a different tool, but it gave an important hint in point 5.

Can you please check in your manifest file, if you have the entry for the main class ?

```
Main-Class: <Main Class name>
```

This should allow the installer to recongnize the Class name.

Comment: I understand your question but I didnt found any main class in java bundler .jar file which was used for instaler.. I understand ur that page.. But can u send the java bundler.jar file which u had used

Comment: I am Strucked in Bundle the JAR ..because that jar bundler jar file cant able to used it

Comment: The Jar Bundler should be able to recognize the main class if you have created the jar file with the manifest file having the Main-Class entry. Have you created the jar file with this Manifest entry ?

Comment: one doubt .. i cant use the jar bundler class.. because jar bundler doesnot has main class but my jar file has main class..

Comment: OKay DO onething send the jar bundler setup to me